# Conditional Probability Simulation Question

Tags: probability, simulation, negative-binomial

I have two variables $X$ and $Y$. $P(X<Y)=0$. I know $P(X=x)$ for all $x$ and $P(Y=y)$ for all $y$, how can I jointly simulate $10,000$ pairs of these values that fit these conditions?

It seems pretty clear that $P(X>x)>=P(Y>x)$ for all $x$. Given $P(X<Y)=0$.

It seems that any $X$ and $Y$ that has $P(X>x)\ge P(Y>y)$ and where $X $and $Y$ have a rank correlation of 1 would satisfy all conditions and I could just simulate with the same percentile for $Y$ and $X$. However I would like for there to be more randomness than this if anyone could find a better solution that still works.

Comment: Your question sounds not very clear. A negative binomial distribution has two parameters, $r$ (the number of successes) and $p$ (the probability of success in each trial). In your problem, does $X$ have the same (or not same) parameters as $Y$ ? If $X$ and $Y$ are independently and randomly generated, you cannot control whether $X < Y$ or $X > Y$. As I can see, the only way to make $P(X < Y)$ is to throw out such pairs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If two events are conditionally independent given an event of prob 1, then the original two events are independent.